# What is the meaning of intelligence being many branched?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

I was reading ISKON Gita Verse 41 chapter 2

> vyavasayatmika buddhir
> ekeha kuru-nandana
> bahu-sakha hy anantas ca
> buddhayo 'vyavasayinam

It is written that

> Those who are on this path are resolute in purpose, and their aim is one. O beloved child of the Kurus, the intelligence of those who are irresolute is many-branched.

My confusion : Why has Prabhupada mentioned  many branch ?  Im not getting the meaning of many branch in this verse

Also, if possible  explain the details meaning of this verse

Comment: Multi-branched thoughts are closer in meaning to [Mind-wandering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind-wandering). Quote from wikipedia page under 'Individual differences' section: "People that are more conscientious are less prone to mind-wandering. Being more conscientious allows people to stay focused on the task better which causes fewer instances of mind-wandering."

Comment: Knowledge is mostly thought of as multi-branched eg. history, physics, etc.

Comment: The knowledge is not the subject of the verse 2-41. The _buddhis_ (insight, enlightenment, intelligence, mental determination) is the subject. See 2-39: when _buddhis_ is yoked with the determination, you shall rid yourself of the bondage of karma. Or See 2-44: In meditation, _buddhis_ is not granted when thoughts are stolen away by the talk of enjoyment and power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the following discussion by Swami Sivananda, it will clear up the confusion.

English Translation By Swami Sivananda
2.41 Here, O joy of the Kurus, there is but a single one-pointed determination; many-branched and endless are the thoughts of the irresolute.
English Commentary By Swami Sivananda
2.41 व्यवसायात्मिका onepointed? बुद्धिः determination? एका single? इह here? कुरुनन्दन O joy of the Kurus? बहुशाखाः manybranched? हि indeed? अनन्ताः endless? च and? बुद्धयः thoughts? अव्यवसायिनाम् of the irresoulte.
Commentary Here? in this path to Bliss there is only one thought of a resolute nature there is singleminded determination. This single thought arises from the right source of knowledge. The student of Yoga collects all the dissipated rays of the mind. He gathers all of them through discrimination? dispassion and concentration. He is free from wavering or vacillation of the mind. The worldlyminded man who is suck in the mire of Samsara has no singleminded determination. He entertains countless thoughts. His mind is always unsteady and vacillating. If thoughts cease? Samsara also ceases. Mind generates endless thoughts and this world comes into being. Thoughts? and names and forms are inseparable. If the thoughts are controlled? the mind is controlled and the Yogi is liberated.

Comment: Probably copied from https://www.yugalsarkar.com/bhagwad-gita-chapter-2-shlok-41-swami-sivananda. In the book there is no commentary on 2.41: https://krishnamurti.abundanthope.org/index_htm_files/BHAGAVAD-GITA-By-SRI-SWAMI-SIVANANDA.pdf (page 24).

Answer (score 1):

A many branched mind/intelligence here means a mind thats distracted by many thoughts and is therefore unable to focus and make a firm decision.

Here Shri krishna is mentioning the qualities that a sadhaka on the path of enlightenment can cultivate. The quality mentioned in the verse is of being resolute in mind.
A person's mind can be cultivated (trained) to be resolute.
Being resolute in mind for one's purpose is absolutely essential to attaining it. (Here the purpose is to be enlightened)

In the verse He is highlighting the key difference between the the resolute and irresolute person.

Resolute mind qualities-
**1) focuses on one thing at a time** (one branched i.e. single minded focus, you can also consider one branch as one branch of thought to understand it better, so more branches means more thoughts. The branch can also refer to neural pathways in the brain).
This single minded focus has to come to point where one reaches a state of flow where one even forgets bodily needs, sense of time and is completely absorbed in the object of one's focus (read ikigai book to understand flow state) in such a state, thought is inessential, infact thoughts cease. Mind will come to an ease.
**2)once a decision is made, mind does not waver from the decision made.**
When you make a firm decision a pathway is formed in your brain. the more you exercise that decision in any given situation the deeper the pathway becomes. that is how habits are formed. let's say you have a habit of expressing gratitude. No matter what situation you face you will always have positive outlook towards life. that pathway (branch) doesn't allow you to branch out and dwell in negative or unproductive thoughts. even if you had one negative thought it doesn't stick to you.

There are many other qualities, but i hope i have answered your queries.

i read this quote a year ago and heard it on spotify (vedanta society) this page is from Ramakrishna mission (vivekananda's) they have in depth lectures on the scripture. i use it to enhance and aid my spiritual practice.

I understood this verse a year later. When i realised that setting more than one big goal a year can be taxing and overwhelming. if u have more than two it can drain ur energy. a year earlier i had set one big (health- lose 19kgs) and one small goal (to get a high-paying career). i achieved it. so this year i set three big goals (A mistake). and i have only been able to work properly on one of it, cause its a big one and it takes up ur time and energy. it is tiring to work on all three. it drains you mentally. that's when the verse hit me. if i need to achieve something, i need to work at it one at a time. this applies to enlightenment as well. Hence people choose to become monks to make it a single-minded effort.

Comment: Yeah I agree, one thing at a time, concentration on that. Trying to do too much depletes us and we get nowhere, and is miserable experience too haha:D